# Cannot connect to database in new installation of Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, database, oracle, connection, oracle12c

I am new to Oracle. I did a fresh installation of Windows 7 x64 on my laptop to install Oracle 12c Enterprise Edition (for learning purpose).

While on admin windows account, I first made a standard windows user with a password to use during the installation. The installation went fine as well as the creation of default ORCL database. The only warning I got was "The selected Oracle home is outside of Oracle base" which I fixed by going back to directories option and setting the directory from "Admin Name" to "Oracle" and it adjusted all directories according to "Oracle" name (I found this solution on internet).

Now after system restart, I am trying to connect to ORCL database using username and password I defined in setup and it just keeps telling me that my logon is incorrect "ora-01017 invalid username/password logon denied" whether I use SQL Developer or SQL Plus command line ?

I have tried searching on internet and didn't find anything much useful or say it's too technical that I don't understand, can anyone explain in simple way that what should I do to make this thing work ?

Thank you and sorry if I sound frustrated, I did this installation twice on Windows 8 which led to errors in my OS then switched Windows 7 and now this third installation is also leading to this error.

Comment: Can you login as sys?

Answer (score 3):

Open SQL Plus and type this "Sys as SYSDBA" for username and don't type any password and it will automatically connected.

Enter user-name: Sys as SYSDBA

Enter password: (don't need)

Screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4seR.png

Comment: Sorry to point this out, but entering SQLPlus does not solve the "SQL Developer" error message. It only proves that SYS exists and can be logged in unfriendly text mode.

Answer (score 0):

remember **password is case-sensitive by default**, maybe this could be your problem.
in oracle 11g and 12c this parameter is case-sensitive., so check your password and write it as you created.
try to login with a user that have CONNECT grant. sys or system should work.

Answer (score 0):

I can relate since I went through the same thing recently. Under Windows 10 (2020).

In my case, I use Spanish language computers, and by default, Oracle 12c for Windows expects an ENGLISH language character set or whatever.

SOLUTION: Go to Windows Regional Settings and select English as the default "regional format". In my case I went with "Spanish (United States)". Then restarted SQL Developer and BOOM: No more cryptic "ora-01017" errors!

GOOD PRACTICE: I only added "SYS" as SYSDBA to connect for the first time (since I have no other users YET). From the much-expected SQL Developer's Worksheet (SYS as SYSDBA) I created a "normal" user. Then, I created a "default (normal)" connection profile for that new  user and started doing DDLs from that connection.

It works flawlessly from there. Hope it helps in your case!